# Dynamically Creating ASP.Net Pages

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to create ASP.Net web pages dynamically. Here is my scenario: I am dynamically creating a huge amount of controls to track data entry that are split up into sections. These sections will play off one another in the sense that if I say I have 5 sections it will create subsections each with the same number of controls and options but divided into groups. This is for tracking the law so it needs to be diverse, dynamic and it obviously has alot of options as the law does. How might one handle something where you have a ton of controls on a page but you want to easily walk the user through the data entry process without confusing them? Our thoughts at this point are as you create the subsections it creates a dynamic webpage that has the subsection controls within it. Or do we need to look to alternative methods - We also thought about hiding the section information doing a display: none with the CSS for each section as you go through the data entry process hiding the controls you are no longer using. how is this possible using ASP.Net with VB? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you want to use client language to manage your controls. May be it's easier to create controls in post back function using vb with viewstate enabled.